Запуск нескольких проектов на nodejs+nginx
Как запустить несколько проектов nodejs+nginx на одном сервере с разными портами?
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name www.domain;
    root /var/www/jor/html;
    index index.html index.xml;
    

    
    location /socket.io/ {
                proxy_pass   http://localhost:3000;

                # the following is required for WebSockets
                proxy_redirect                off;
                proxy_set_header              Host             $host;
                proxy_set_header              Port             $server_port;
                proxy_set_header              X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header              X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header              X-NginX-Proxy    true;
                proxy_pass_request_headers    on;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
        
    location = /robots.txt {
        alias /var/www/jor/html/robots.txt;
    }
}

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

io.on('connection', socket => {
      io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit('hello', "eee");
});
})
  //connection.end();
server.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});


Точно так же, как и один проект, но просто указать другие порты, наверное?

Если бы было так, я бы не писал сюда))

Сервер то запускается, но клиент подключается только к первому порту (3000), ко второму не подключается... io.connect() подключается к первому порту, io.connect('http://localhost:3001') не подключается

Если вы пытаетесь подключиться напрямую к node.js, то зачем здесь nginx вообще?

Я nodejs использую только для сокета

Но в любом случае — что конкретно означает «не подключается»? Почему не подключается? Что мешает подключиться?

Ошибка на клиенте: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Значит на сервере не оказалось никого, кто принимал бы подключения на порту 3001

Ну я же и написал сюда, для того что бы решить эту проблему..

Оба сервера запущены один на 3000 порту, другой на 3001 порту, к 3000 подключение работает, на втором не работает

Как вы проверяете, что сервер на 3001 порту действительно запущен?

curl http://localhost:3001 возвращает страницу ошибки (не найдена страница), если сервер выключить на этом порту, то ошибка подключения

И одновременно с этим на клиенте всё равно возникает ошибка ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED? Раз уж вы написали localhost — сервер, клиент и curl точно все находятся на одном и том же устройстве?

Естественно...)

Или у вас чудеса какие-то, или вы что-то не договариваете, но у меня закончились идеи что именно

Ну вот и я не могу понять.... Но мне кажется что эти порты (сокета) надо отрабатывать как то на стороне nginx

Вот что то похожее нашел https://stackoverflow.com/a/63439320/23800248
